Time to reach max height with an inverse square law relationship for gravity.
A spaceship is launched from Earth's surface with acceleration given by
$$
a = -\frac{gR^{2}}{x^{2}}
$$
where

$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity at the Earth's surface,
$R$ is the radius of the Earth
and $x$ is the spaceship's displacement.

$$
\mbox{Prove that}\quad
T=\left(1+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}
$$
It is launched with an initial speed of $U$.

I am having a great deal of trouble finding an expression for $x$ in terms of $t$.
I have found an expression for $v$ in terms of $x$ which is
$$
v^2=U^2-2gR^2\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
I have even found the maximum height above the Earth's surface which is
$$
H=\frac{RU^2}{2gR-U^2}
$$
but I can't seem to use these values.
Square rooting both sides of the velocity equation seems to yield a very horrible integral and I don't see how the answer can be found from that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Its not clear what is the start condition, velocity, direction and what is the acceleration if any. a is  the acceleration due to gravity at hight x over earth mit point.

Did you copy the answer to another exercise for $T$ ? It doesn't depend on $U$ or $H$, which is very doubtful, because it would mean that this time would be same for all launches $-$ and it ressembles the formula for the period of a pendulum.

Let's take a step back, because your problem suffers from several problem of parametrization at the very beginning. So, a mass $m$ is launched vertically from the Earth's ground with an initial velocity $v_0$. Its motion will follow a vertical axis $z$ and let's fix the origin of the latter at the Earth's center. Finally, for the sake of simplicity, let's assume that the body $m$ is subjected to the gravitational force only.
Since gravity is conservative, we may apply the principle of energy conservation. At the start, the energy of the mass $m$ has two components, namely the kinetic energy due to the initial velocity, as well as the gravitational energy of the ground, i.e. $E_{init} = \frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + G\frac{mM}{R}$, where $R$ is the Earth's radius. At the maximum height $z_{max}$, all the kinetic energy has been converted into potential energy, hence $E_{fin} = \frac{GM}{z_{max}}$. Equating these two quantities, we get :
$$
\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + G\frac{mM}{R} = G\frac{mM}{z_{max}}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
z_{max} = \frac{R}{1+\frac{v_0^2R}{2GM}}
$$
Now, we would like to determine the time $T$ needed to reach $z_{max}$. Yet, the same equation for energy conservation at an arbitrary position $z$, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 + G\frac{mM}{R} = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{z}^2 + G\frac{mM}{z}, 
\tag{*}
$$
leads to
$$
\dot{z} = -\sqrt{a + \frac{b}{z}}, 
\text{  with  }
a = v_0^2 + \frac{GM}{R}
\text{  and  }
b = -GM,
$$
and can be integrated by seperation of the variables, as it follows :
$$
T = \int_0^T\mathrm{d}t = -\int_0^{z_{max}} \sqrt{\frac{z}{az+b}} \,\mathrm{d}z
$$
Note that the minus is due to the decreasing speed. The result is quite nasty and involves a hyperbolic arcsin; it can be computed thanks to a suitable change of variable.

Final remarks.
Alternatively, we could have started from Newton's third law, i.e. $m\ddot{z} = -G\frac{mM}{z^2}$ for $z \ge R$ (the gravitional field is different for $z < R$), multiplied it by $\dot{z}$ and integrated it, but we would have recovered the equation for energy conservation in $(*)$, actually. Finally, if $z_{max} \ll R$, you may apply the same procedure with the gravitational potential $mgz$ instead.

Starting from @Abezhiko's answer , the integral is not so bad
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{z}{a z+b}}\,dz$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{z}{a z+b}}=\frac 1 x \implies z=\frac{b}{x^2-a}\implies dz=-\frac{2 b x}{\left(x^2-a\right)^2}\,dx$$
$$I=-2b \int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2-a\right)^2}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{\left(x^2-a\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4 a^{3/2}}\left(\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{a}}-\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{a }}  \right)+\frac 1{4a}\left(\frac{1}{\left(x+\sqrt{a}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(x-\sqrt{a}\right)^2} \right)$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{\left(x^2-a\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4 a^{3/2}}\log
   \left(\frac{x+\sqrt{a}}{x-\sqrt{a}}\right)-\frac 1{2a}\frac{x}{x^2-a}$$ Go back to $z$ and use the bounds.

I cannot imagine where the answer is coming from. The energy theorem for radial motion reads, energy for all times equals energy at top $r=h, r'=0$
$$\frac{dr^2}{2 dt^2} - \frac{ g R^2}{r} = - \frac{g R^2}{h}$$
Solving the integral for
$$\text{dt}^2=\frac{\text{dr}^2}{2 g R^2 \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{h}\right)}$$
yields
$$T(r,h,R, g) :=\sqrt{\frac{h}{2 g}} \ \left(\frac{r}{R}\  \sqrt{\frac{h}{r}-1}+\frac{h}{R} \ \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{h}{r}-1}\right)\right)$$
verified by
$$\frac{1}{2\left( \frac{dt}{dr}\right)^2} = \ \frac{1}{2 \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(\sqrt{\frac{h}{2 g}} \left(c+\frac{r \sqrt{\frac{h}{r}-1}}{R}+\frac{h \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{h}{r}-1}\right)}{R}\right)\right)\right)^2} \  = \ \frac{g R^2}{r}-\frac{g R^2}{h} $$
